# SVG textpath element renders incorrectly in Firefox when generated using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg

The following code renders fine in Chrome, IE11 and Opera, but shows the text in the upper left corner in Firefox:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 1000 1000");
svg.id = "clockSVG";
document.body.appendChild(svg);

var defs = document.createElement('defs');
defs.id = "defs";
svg.appendChild(defs);

var path = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"path");
path.setAttribute("d","M75,20 l100,0 l100,30 q0,100 150,100");
path.setAttribute("id","myTextPath2");
defs.appendChild(path);

var text = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
text.setAttribute("x","10");
text.setAttribute("y","100");
text.setAttribute("fill","black");
svg.appendChild(text);

var textPath = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"textPath");
textPath.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, "xlink:href", "#myTextPath2");
textPath.textContent = "Text along a more advanced path with lines and curves.";
text.appendChild(textPath);
svg.appendChild(text);
```

If I call text.getBBox(), it reveals that it hugs the left screen edge and somehow receives a negative y-value:

```
SVGRect { x: 0, y: -14.825797080993652, width: 355.164306640625, height: 18.532245635986328 }
```

After some experimentation I found that for textPath elements to render correctly in Firefox when declared in the HTML, the content of the textPath element must be on the same line as the tags.

This will render with a weird offset:

```
<text x="10" y="100" style="stroke: #000000;">
    <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath2">
        Text along a more advanced path with lines and curves.
    </textPath>
</text>
```

This will render correctly:

```
<text x="10" y="100" style="stroke: #000000;">
    <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath2">Text along a more advanced path with lines and curves.</textPath>
</text>
```

(If the text's x and y attributes are set to 0 or left blank, however, it renders correctly)

So I tried constructing the necessary HTML as a one-line string and inserting that:

```
var textPathString = '<textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath2">Text along a more advanced path with lines and curves.</textPath>';
text.innerHTML = textPathString;
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't render anything (doesn't work in Chrome, either).

How can I make sure Firefox displays textpaths generated by JavaScript correctly?

Are these bugs and should I report them?

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated as my project relies on being able to dynamically generate textpaths!

Comment: Yes for the textPath (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG&component=SVG), no for the innerHTML thing (that's a known issue)

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted the bug. In the meantime, I guess I'll have to find a workaround to generate the HTML beforehand.

Comment: Alice figured out what was wrong createElement("defs") should be createElementNS. If there's another bug after that is fixed then do raise another bug rather than reopening the one you already raised.

Comment: Nicely spotted! Can't believe I've been banging my head over this. The help is very much appreciated! If you'll post your solution as an answer to this question I'll mark is as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written `createElement("defs")` rather than `createElementNS` which you have used at all other points.